# OpServer "No configuration" error when provider="ad"

Tags: opserver

I have downloaded the source from OpServer, set up two instances in SQLsettings.json and set the provider in SecuritySettings.config to "alladmin", which works just fine.

Now I want to change this from `alladmin` to `AD`, so the user has to enter his credentials to access the dashboard This is the current config:

```
<SecuritySettings provider="ad">
        <InternalNetworks>
                <Network name="Internal virtual" cidr="172.16.2.0/23" />
                <Network name="Internal physical" cidr="172.16.8.0/23" />
        </InternalNetworks>
</SecuritySettings>
```

After successfully entering my username/password I am recieving the following error, regardless if the InternalNetworks node is present or not:

> Uh oh! No Configuration! No configuration data was found, meaning no
>   opserver sections are configured or available.
>
> See the Readme.txt in the /config directory and .example files for
>   examples of a basic JSON configuration...or you can implement your own
>   provider to get settings from anywhere.

Unfortunately the example file and the readme are of no great help here. What do I need to change in order to get it working without the `alladmin` setting?

For those interested: the sourcecode and the example config files are available here:
https://github.com/opserver/Opserver

Comment: As Trondh mentions you need to setup the different configuration files appropriately depending on what you want to monitor. I have a blog post that provides some examples of what we use that may be helpful http://patpack.blogspot.com/2013/10/setting-up-stackexchanges-opserver.html

Comment: And ... it's in the bookmark folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you are logged in all right, but haven't configured the rest of the settings. Remove the ".example" extension from the dashboard file for example, and the console should throw some errors about not being able to poll data from the configured servers.